# How to retain style change of an element across postback?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have jquery click event for an element, I am changing the background color on click. But in postback I am not able to keep the change. How to retain this change?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it out-of the box- **web applications are stateless.**

You will need give a flag indicating what should be the background color.
If you meant by the `mvc` tag `Asp.net-Mvc`... You can use the `ViewBag.Color` for the flag.

**Controller:**

```
public ActionResult Foo()
{
 ...   
    ViewBag.Color = "Green";    
    return View();
}
```

**View**

```
<body style="background-color:'@(ViewBag.Color)'">
```